# Split string after every nth character

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1

Is there a way how to split string after every nth character in PostgreSQL? I thought `regexp_split_to_array` can be used to do this:

```
select unnest(regexp_split_to_array('abcdefgh', E'...regexp here...'));
```

Example input: `abcdefgh`

Required output (split after every 2nd character):

```
ab
cd
ef
gh
```

Required output (split after every 3rd character):

```
abc
def
gh
```

What regexp will do this? Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `substring` and `generate_series`:

```
regress=> select substring('abcdefgh' from n for 2) from generate_series(1, length( 'abcdefgh' ), 2) n;
 substring 
-----------
 ab
 cd
 ef
 gh
(4 rows)

regress=> select substring('abcdefgh' from n for 3) from generate_series(1, length( 'abcdefgh' ), 3) n;
 substring 
-----------
 abc
 def
 gh
(3 rows)
```

This is trivially wrapped into an inlineable SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION string_nchars(text, integer) RETURNS setof text AS $$
SELECT substring($1 from n for $2) FROM generate_series(1, length($1), $2) n;
$$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Usage:

```
regress=> SELECT string_nchars('abcdefgh',3);
 string_nchars 
---------------
 abc
 def
 gh
(3 rows)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use lookaheads.  Lookbehind would be better, but are not implemented.

This only works if the length of the string is even (or a multiple of the split size), and might be inefficient for large strings.

```
select unnest(regexp_split_to_array('abcdefgh', E'(?=(..)+$)'));
```

If it is not a multiple, then something like:

```
select reverse(unnest) from unnest(regexp_split_to_array(reverse('abcdefgh'), E'(?=(...)+$)'));
```

But I'd probably install plperl and then do it in Perl.